# Exception creating a card in stripe

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm trying to add a card to a customer with the following code:

```
cu = stripe.Customer.retrieve(customer_id)
cu.cards.create(card=token)
```

However, I am getting the following exception:

```
'ListObject' object has no attribute 'create'
```

It seems cu.cards does not have a "create" method.

I'm using the 1.12.0 library for python.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welp, I was dumb, and I guess I'll just leave this question and answer here in case anyone else can benefit from it.

I was not using the latest version of the api on my account.  Apparently you can click on Account Settings->API Keys, and upgrade the API that your account uses.  I was using a rather old version of the api.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I was getting the same error, but in addition to upgrading the API version I had to upgrade the python library by running `pip install -U stripe`